# Eclipse ADT: how to build the same debuggable app on two PCs with the same certificate?

Tags: android, eclipse, certificate, code-signing

Is it possible to tell Eclipse to automatically sign debug APKs with the same key, so that many PCs can be set up to use that same key? If two programmers are developing the same app and test it on the same device, they have to uninstall the app every time they pass the device to each other. Quite annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes just use a custom key.store and keep it in your project svn.

Then in Preferences > Android > Build > Custom debug Keystore

link to it there:

[image: Custom Keystore]

For Ant build's it's a bit more complex and you have to then copy the same debug.keystore into ./android/ on both machines.

./android is usually in your user directory on mac

./android is usually in documents and settings / your username / my documents on Windows

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can't believe I've missed this setting.